# When directed graph is linear, return the nodes in order. Otherwise fail

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dag

## The Problem

I have a set of `edges` `(a, b)`, where `a` and `b` are nodes in a directed, acyclic graph (DAG).

The number of edges is guaranteed to be the number of nodes - 1.

I am looking for an algorithm that finds a sequence of nodes `[n_1, ... n_n]` so that the sequence contains *all* nodes in the graph, and that all edges `(n_i, n_i+1)` for `0 < i < n` exist in `edges`. 
If that sequence is not possible because the given set of `edges` is not equal to the set of edges required, then I need an error to be thrown.

Edit: the graph may have an arbitrary number of disconnected components. I obviously don't consider a graph with multiple disconnected components as linear.

## Ideas so far

Note that I am checking that the number of `edges` is exactly the number of edges required for such a sequence to exist. As a result, the algorithm can fail when there are two edges that share a source or a destination. However, I still need to get that sequence.

I realize that topological sort returns a linear order of a directed graph, which satisfies my requirements. However, I still want to fail when the graph is not exactly linear like that, instead of getting a linear order anyways.

Maybe I can validate, then do a topological sort. But that sounds inefficient. I am also not sure about the formal names of things in this problem, so it's hard to simply look up an algorithm. I feel like I am missing some simple connection or trick here.

**Could you provide me with an algorithm that accomplishes this? I'll take pseudocode or any language of your choice.**

Comment: Have you tried thinking of an algorithm using BFS or DFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an algorithm that at least passes my test cases:

```
let N = set of all nodes
let E = set of all edges

if (|E| != |N|-1) fail

let possibleStartNodes = new set containing all of N
let nexts = new dictionary from node -> node

foreach (prev, next) in E:
  if (next not in possibleStartNodes) fail 
  remove next from possibleStartNodes
  nexts[prev] = next
end foreach

if (|possibleStartNodes| != 1) fail

let currentNode = the one node in possibleStartNodes
let ordering = new list
ordering.push(currentNode)

while (nexts contains value for currentNode) 
  ordering.push(next)
  currentNode = next
end while

return ordering
```

$O(n)$ looks pretty reasonable to me. Are there any ways to improve?

**Edit:** I would appreciate any hints about the correct technical terms for the concepts I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quite non-optimal algorithm, to get you started.

Go over all edges $(a,b)$. For each edge, go again over all edges, and check how many times $a$ appears. Stop once you discover $a$ that appears only once (if this never happens, reject). We will take $n_1 = a$.

Go over all edges again, looking for the unique edge $(n_1,b)$ in which $n_1$ appears. Take $n_2 = b$.

Go over all edges again, looking for an edge $(n_2,c)$ in which $n_2$ appears on the left (if there is no such edge, reject). Take $n_3 = c$.

Continue in this way, finding $n_4,\ldots,n_n$.

This algorithm runs in $O(n^2)$. Using hashing, you should be able to improve it to $O(n)$.

Comment: Are you sure this works? If there are any two edges `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` where `a = c`, then the graph is not linear. Every node should exist exactly once as a the source of an edge and once as a destination. Otherwise it should fail.

Comment: You also need to check that the different $n_i$ that you find are distinct.